# PHP MySQL how to retrieve records that match several different values in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have an array on php that contains some IDs of the records i want to retrieve, an i'm doing it with a loop an executing the query several times to get them all.

```
foreach ($receivers as $id) {

            $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT phone FROM contact WHERE idcontact = ?");

            $sth->execute(array($id));

            $res= $sth->fetch();
            echo $res['phone'] ;
            }
```

how can I do it in a single query, so that I'll not bother the database with hundreds queries ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT phone FROM contact WHERE idcontact IN (" . implode(",",$receivers) . ")");
```

Source: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php

Better source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `IN()` predicate with query parameters:

```
$placeholders = implode(",", array_fill(1, count($receivers), "?"));

$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT phone FROM contact WHERE idcontact IN ($placeholders)");

$sth->execute($receivers);
```